# SQL where clause count for individual records

Tags: sql, count, logic, row, where-clause

my sql is a bit rusty (not really that great to begin with!)

I'm trying to write a query that searches through a single table, now within this table there are numerous customers buying some item. Now obviously I can search by the customer, as in

```
select * from purchases where customer_name "Brian" and product_name like 'Al%;
```

My problem is what I'm wanting to do is, in a query like that, I want to list all the customer names that have purchased like 'Al%' and the count.

So "Alcohol", etc, would only ever be once per record in the data. But say "Brian" purchases alcohol, all day breakfast, alcohol (all in separate records). I would want to count those, so my return would be "Brian      3".

My final failed attempt was below (not sure it will help!)

```
select purchases.customer_name, COUNT(purchases.product_name like 'Al%') As Al purchases from purchases;
```

Thanks in advance. It may be something very simple and I'm totally messing it up in my head!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add **GROUP BY**

```
select purchases.customer_name, purchases.product_name, COUNT(purchases.product_name) from purchases where customer_name "Brian" and product_name like 'Al% GROUP BY purchases.product_name, purchases.customer_name;
```

You will get

**Brian, Alcohol, 2**

**Brian, Alcohol Jin, 3**

Answer (score 0):

Write This Way::

That Can Solve Your Problem.

> select purchases.customer_name, COUNT(purchases.product_name) As Al
>   from purchases where purchases.product_name like 'Al%' Group by
>   purchases.product_name;